# Least squares approximation, find probable value of A

Tags: analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

Measurments $(t_k, C_k), t=1..n ; t_k, C_k > 0$ suggest that $C(t) = 2^{({At^{2}+2018})^{-1}}$. Using mean square approximation find probable value for constant $A$. I've been struggling with this problem for hours, can someone please help me with finding the solution? Please, i really need help...

Comment: this $t=1..n$ is a typo? and should read $k=1..n$ I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: I assume *"Using mean square approximation"* means to apply [least sqare method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) (Carl Gauss claimes to be his idea).
Next: $(C_k-C(t_k))^2$ must be derivable, otherwise I have to reach for a numerical aproximation. To avoid this an "alternate definition" of the square delta to minimize could be used, kind of *makeshift or workaround*. This is why I use (I emphasize **as stopgap**)$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left (\frac{log(2)}{log(C_k)}-(a*t_k+2018)\right )^2$$
what is$$\log\left(2\right)^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\log\left(c_{k}\right)^2}\right)-2a\log\left(2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{t_{k}}{\log\left(c_{k}\right)}\right)+\mathrm{4036}\log\left(2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\log\left(c_{k}\right)}\right)+a^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}^2\right)-
\mathrm{4036}a\left(\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}\right)+\mathrm{4072324}n$$
derived once to $a$
$$2\left(-\log\left(2\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{t_{k}}{\log\left(c_{k}\right)}\right)+a\left(\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}^2\right)-\mathrm{2018}\sum_{k=1}^n\,t_{k}\right)$$
solved for $a$
$$a=\frac{\log\left(2\right)\displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{t_{k}}{\log\left(c_{k}\right)}\right)+\mathrm{2018}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}^2}$$
Pronto.
In case this kind of workaround is unwanted the result may serve as initial value for an aproximation.

Comment: BTW, the proof is missing that this is a minimum. Derived the first equation twice for $a$ results $\displaystyle 2\sum_{k=1}^n t_{k}^2$ what is for sure $\gt 0$ -- so the a. m. result is a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define function $C(t)$ as exponential map $2^{(A t^2 + 2018)^{-1}}$. We call it $y$. We may apply logarithm on base 2 given by operation $\log_2$ and obtain $\log_2(y) = (A t^2 + 2018)^{-1}$. We invert both sides of the equality and obtain $\frac{1}{\log_2(y)} = A t^2 + 2018$. Finally, we get the desired format for application of least squares method: $\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{\log_2(y)} - 2018 \right)}_{f(t, y)} = A t^2$. Since we have multiple readings, we obtain more equations than variables. The best solution for such linear system $Ax = b$ is is given by the product of Moore-Penrose matrix $A^+$ by right vector $b$ i.e. $A^+ b$.

\begin{equation}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots \\
f(t_k, y_k) \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}}_{f_n} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots \\
t_k^2 \\
\vdots
\end{bmatrix}}_{\tau_n} A
\end{equation}

For our case, the Moore-Penrose inverse matrix $\tau_n^+$ is given by vector $\frac{\tau_n^\intercal}{\tau_n^\intercal \tau_n}$. Therefore, the best value for variable $A$ is given by the ratio $\frac{\tau_n^\intercal f_n}{\tau_n^\intercal \tau_n}$.

Comment: Letting $z = \frac{1}{\log_2(y)}-2018$ and $u=t^2$, the problem comes down to estimate the slope $A$ in the simple regression model without intercept $z = Au + \text{error}$. This estimate is $\frac{\sum u_k y_k}{\sum u_k^2}$ and that does not coincide with your solution. What is wrong?

Comment: And your solution is the same as the estimate of the intercept in the intercept-only model $z/u = A + \text{error}$.

Comment: I think these approaches are incorrect. Because one has to minimize $\sum (C_k - C(t_k))^2$, and this is a different problem. We need a software able to perform a nonlinear least squares approximation.

Comment: I fixed the solution with yout suggestion. I did not consider the case such that $t_k$ is 0.

Comment: According to OP $t_k, C_k \gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the question is asking to find the value of $A$ minimizing $\sum_{k=1}^n {\bigl(C_k - C(t_k)\bigr)}^2$. You need a software to solve this *nonlinear least squares* problem. With R, here is how:

```
# simulate some data
A <- 2
f <- function(t) {
  2^(1 / (A*t^2 + 2018))
}
t <- 1:100 # the t_k
C <- f(t) + rnorm(100, sd = 0.1) # the C_k = f(t_k) + small deviation

# run the nonlinear least-squares procedure
nls(C ~ 2^(1 / (A*t^2 + 2018)), start = list(A = 2))
```

However I tried and obtained a bad estimate of $A$ with these simulated data.